# How to import custom scripts when building a pip package?

Tags: python-3.x

I am building a pip package. But I am getting a error when running my pip package.
The error is as following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/factocli", line 21, in <module>
    from custom_imports import install_server
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'custom_imports'
```

It cannot import the scripts. I guess it doesn't install those scripts..?

This is my setup.py

```
import setuptools


with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()
setuptools.setup(
    name='factocli',  
    version='0.2.7',
    scripts=['factocli'] ,
    author="#####",
    author_email="#######",
    description="A Cli for managing a Factorio Headless Server",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="#######",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    install_requires=["PyInquirer", "wget"],
```

The folder structure is as following:

```
facto
 ---build
 ---custom_imports
    ---Install_server.py
    ---Remove_server.py
    ---Update_server.py
 ---dist
 ---factocli.egg-info
factocli
LICENSE
README.md
setup.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I imported in the setup.py the script files and when building the pip package it now sees it.
The question can we closed.